# How to learn difficult triads on piano

Tags: piano, technique

I stumbled upon a quite difficult triad. According to the video I saw, the fingering used is 1 2 5, but the way I have to position my hand is very unnatural, and it is really hard to play this correctly. How do I get the hang of notes that need a weird hand position, not just in this piece but any other?

[image]

I tried adding a gif showing how it looks but it is too big :C

Comment: How big are your hands? If your right hand can span an octave, then the resulting right hand position doesn't seem that unnatural to me. Also, try playing them in a more detached manner--i.e. rocking your hand back and forth between the highest and lowest notes instead of spanning the interval all the time.

Comment: I can reach an octave + 1 note

Comment: That sounds just like my hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing for fast notes with 1 (thumb) one a black key is to move your hand in-between the black keys*. It will take a bit of practice hitting the white keys there, but it's really efficient.

I would play the bars you show using solely 1, 2, 5. The interval D--Bb' can be somewhat largish for 2--5 fingering, but some practice should do; given you can play 9ths, your hand should manage.

One more trick is to move your whole body a bit to the left. This gives your forearm and elbow a bit more free movement, and in turn eases the position of the wrist.

---

*) I hope you've got a real hammer piano, or if it's a keyboard, at least one with good mechanics. It's very difficult to play between the black keys on poor keyboards.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I have a digital piano with both weighted keys and hammer action. And because I have difficulties playing the white notes by hitting them from "top" (because they are heavier there), I tried to position my hand so I hit them from "bottom". Can you reccomend me any practice to improve?

Comment: @Zektor Trust me that hammer action is easier to play between the keys than keyboard's muddy action. As for some exercises, you can try repeated notes: play the same bars as `a a d d bb bb a a d d bb bb a a d d bb bb a a d d bb bb gg bb dd ...`, that's one thing that could help. But in general, it's practice, practice and practice.

Answer (score 0):

This passage lies comfortably for the hand.  I suspect that either your hand hasn't finished growing or you have a small span.  Either way, you can roll your hand slightly in order to reach all the notes.  You should avoid having an unnatural or weird hand position.